# Do we need to manually load the firmware in /lib/firmware?

Tags: firmware

I saw many firmware files in `/lib/firmware`.

Do we need to load it manually or will OS auto load it if it sees a corresponding device?

Comment: How are you going to "load" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you’re talking about a Linux system. If so, you don’t need to load anything manually, the device drivers will arrange for the appropriate firmware to be loaded (if it’s available).